# Why doesn't the hidden container reappear when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden container that contains comments, and a `<div>` with a `<p>` inside that says "Show all comments" that I click to show the comments. When I click the div it shows the hidden comments container perfectly, but when I click it again it doesn't hide the comments container. I am thinking there is something wrong with my jQuery code maybe?

```
var commentsHidden = $( ".comments-container" ).is( ":hidden" );

if (commentsHidden) {
  $( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
      $('.comments-container').show('slow');
      $('.see_hide').text('Hide Comments');
    });

} else {

    $( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
      $('.comments-container').hide();
    });

};
```

Comment: can you include the html in the question

Comment: The condition should be included in the `click` handler, not the other way around.

Comment: The ifs do not not magically run and bind the new events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize commentsHidden it is never updated so it always has its initial value. You need to check if its hidden on every click. So you don't need an if statement to attach the event. Just attach a single click event and check inside the event if its hidden and continue accordingly.

```
$(".see-all").click(function() {
    var commentsHidden = $(".comments-container").is(":hidden");
    if (commentsHidden) {
        $('.comments-container').show('slow');
        $('.see_hide').text('Hide Comments');
    } else {
        $('.comments-container').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem! Good luck =]

Answer (score 0):

When you call `on('click', ..)` or its shortcut `click(..)`, you install a new handler. What ends up happening is that you have multiple handlers on the same object, and they *all* get called. Instead, either install the handler only once:

```
// In global code or code that gets executed upon module load
// Only once!
$(".see-all").click(function() {
  if ($( ".comments-container" ).is( ":hidden" )) {
    $('.comments-container').show('slow');
    $('.see_hide').text('Hide Comments');
  } else {
    $('.comments-container').hide();
  }
});
```

or [unbind](https://api.jquery.com/off/) the old handler:

```
$( ".see-all" ).off('click'); // Unbind all click handlers

var commentsHidden = $( ".comments-container" ).is( ":hidden" );
if (commentsHidden) {
  $( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
    $('.comments-container').show('slow');
    $('.see_hide').text('Hide Comments');
  });
} else {
  $( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
    $('.comments-container').hide();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the flag state inside the click function(). The way you have it now will only bind the click handler once on page load.

```
$( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
    var commentsHidden = $( ".comments-container" ).is( ":hidden" );
    if (commentsHidden) {
        $('.comments-container').show('slow');
        $('.see_hide').text('Hide Comments');
    } else {
         $('.comments-container').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to

```
$( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
  var commentsHidden = $( ".comments-container" ).is( ":hidden" );
  if (commentsHidden) {
      $('.comments-container').show('slow');
      $('.see_hide').text('Hide Comments');
    });
  } else {
    $( ".see-all" ).click(function() {
      $('.comments-container').hide();
    });
  }
});
```

The click handler should only be bound once, and you need to check whether comments are hidden each time the p element is clicked.